# bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.0-examples.jar wordcount /tmp/gutenberg gutenberg-output

Tags: java, hadoop

I'm testing the Hadoop following this ["Running Hadoop On Ubuntu Linux (Single-Node Cluster)"](https://www.michael-noll.com/tutorials/running-hadoop-on-ubuntu-linux-single-node-cluster/) tutorial.

There is no output after running this command:

```
bin/hadoop jar hadoop-0.20.0-examples.jar wordcount /tmp/gutenberg gutenberg-output
```

If there is an error I will see something, however I see nothing. So, what should I do?

Is it an error, or something wrong with configuration?

Please give me your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

From the [Wiki](http://wiki.apache.org/hadoop/WordCount) it looks like the second parameter gutenberg-output is the output file.  Have you checked the contents of this file?  The example is given in a file rather than output to the console.